# How to fix error from mailto link within iframe

Tags: html, iframe, mailto

I am creating a webpage with a mailto link inside an iframe. I get an error when clicking on this link. The error does not occur when I put the mailto link outside the iframe. It might relate to gmail being my default mail handler, but I want the link to work for gmail users, and of course also for users of other email clients. How can I fix this?

Here's the relevant content from the .html file that goes into the iframe:

```
<a target="_parent" href="mailto:xxx@xxx.xxx">Contact XXX</a>
```

And here's the error message.

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc%3Dmailto%26url%3Dmailto:xxx@xxx.xxx&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2
>   does not permit framing.

If it's relevant, I'm testing on Firefox, but of course I'd like a cross-browser solution.

Comment: It might be the target part.  What about changing it to _blank instead of _parent?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but I tried it and still get the same error.

Comment: Which part of "does not permit framing" confuses you ? :)

Comment: Er, the part where it doesn't tell me how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

1. Change to target="_blank" to open a new tab;

```
    <a target="_blank" href="mailto:xxx@xxx.xxx">Contact XXX</a>
```

2. Allow gmail to handle "mailto":

   - Use chrome to access gmail.com;
   - Look at the right-side of the address bar for the Protocol Handler icon;
   - Click above icon, and choose "allow" option;

Comment: This doesn't work for me. All target attributes get wiped in my scenario within the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

I also had same issue within iframe . you can just add following code onclick event of element for open mailto window

```
window.top.location='mailto:xxx@xxx.xxx';
```

this will open your mailto window within iframe

Comment: This worked for me within the onClick event of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Made a quick test page:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="test2.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the content of test2.html:

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.com" target="_parent">test email</a>
```

And it works fine with Gmail set as the default handler. Not sure what the problem is on your end...

Edit: Are you possibly using an extension to make mailto links open in Gmail instead of setting it as the default handler?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like it. It did work OK for me on Chrome with a desktop and Safari on an iPad, though. In both cases Gmail wasn't set up as the default handler. Maybe some idiosyncrasy of Firefox?

Comment: What you have is a setting in Firefox to handle mailto through gmail, I had gmail as the default mail handler for Windows 8.

The problem is that browsers don't let you open links from iframes that do not belong to the same domain, this is a security feature. 

You can probably use JavaScript window.open to accomplish what you need.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to set `target="_top"`

Comment: Mind to explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: Backend is probably setup to permit url changes inside iframe. _top target will pass mailto url to the top window without these restrictions

Comment: This doesn't work for me.